# Display custom debug info inside page and not before head

Tags: hooks

I'm learning to develop a plugin in Wordpress.

I would render my custom debug info inside page and not before the head (so I think it's a hook issue?).

This is my plugin code:

```
if (is_admin()) {

    require_once SVERBA__PLUGIN_DIR.'class.sverba-admin.php';
    add_action( 'init', array( 'SverbaAdmin', 'init' ) );


    if (SVERBA__DEBUG > 0) {

        add_action( 'init', array( 'SverbaAdmin', 'printDebug' ) );

    }

}
```

And this is the `class.sverba-admin.php` code (only a part, not all):

```
public function printDebug() {

    echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<h1>Variabili</h1>';
        echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li>'.var_dump(self::$initiated).'</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

It works, but debug info are printed BEFORE the head. I want them inside the page, for example in the div with class "wrap"

[image]

Comment: You have to create an admin screen and display your data or hook your function to your desired admin page. `init` hook fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent, meaning runs before hmtl rendering. Also you could use `<li><pre> .  var_dump(self::$initiated) </pre></li>` for better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't print any debug info into the page directly. WordPress offers a `wp-content/debug.log` file which you can use.

Enable debug and debug_log in your `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); // turn debug mode on
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); // do not display errors
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // save errors to wp-content/debug.log
define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true ); // save queries for debug
```

Add this handy function to your `functions.php` or plugin file

```
/**
 * Simple debug trace to wp-content/debug.log
 * @usage _log( $var );
 */
if ( ! function_exists( '_log' ) ) {
    function _log( $log ) {

        if ( true !== WP_DEBUG ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
            error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
        } else {
            error_log( $log );
        }

    }
}
```

Use it in your code whenever you need to print some debug info

```
_log( $my_var );
```

Open `wp-content/debug.log` and see you data printed there. I usually keep it as a pinned file in my IDE (PHPStorm).

Comment: I know, I know, I use the log file, sorry, I did not tell before, but, I want print info also on page (for test && debug). I don't know how print inside "div.wrap".

Comment: If you absolutely must print any info on the admin pages, here are two actions you might check:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/in_admin_header
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices
The second one allows you to utilize admin notices, while the first one gives you direct access to the <div id="wpcontent">.